# Why does my "val_accuracy" start from a high value?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, prediction, confusion-matrix

I am using breast cancer wisconsin data and working on it with ANN, in keras library.

> I've added codes and a part of data below, I hope it's readable and understandable.

One row from dataset:`1000025,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2`

Prediction results:

> Test Loss: 0.05948319600096771 - Test Accuracy: 0.9809523820877075

[As seen, confusion matrix looks fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wflM4.png)

[Here, loss graphic looks okay but accuracy graphic made me confused. Why does training_accuracy starts with a high value and doesnt change much?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tqaV.png)

> Here's the main part of code, after importing libraries:

```
data = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data')
data_new = data.drop(['1000025'],axis=1)

X = data_new.iloc[:,0:8].values
Y = data_new.iloc[:,9].values

labelencoder_= LabelEncoder()
Y = labelencoder_.fit_transform(Y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.15, random_state = 0)

#Feature Scaling
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(8, input_dim=8))
classifier.add(Activation("relu"))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(Dense(32))
classifier.add(Activation("relu"))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(Dense(16))
classifier.add(Activation("relu"))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(Dense(1))
classifier.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.11)

test_loss, test_acc = classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

print('\nTest Loss:', test_loss)
print('Test Accuracy:', test_acc)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

> And plots of the graphics and confusion matrix:

```
#LOSS---
training_loss = history.history['loss']
test_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epoch_count = range(1, len(training_loss) + 1)

plt.plot(epoch_count, training_loss, 'r-')
plt.plot(epoch_count, test_loss, 'b-')
plt.legend(['Training Loss', 'Test Loss'])
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.show()


#ACCURACY---
training_acc = history.history['accuracy']
test_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

epoch_count2 = range(1, len(training_acc) + 1)

plt.plot(epoch_count2, training_acc, 'r-')
plt.plot(epoch_count2, test_acc, 'b-')
plt.legend(['Training Accuracy','Test Accuracy'])
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()


ConfMatrix = confusion_matrix(y_test,pred)
ax = sns.heatmap(ConfMatrix, annot=True, cmap="gray", fmt="d", xticklabels = ['Benign', 'Malignant'], yticklabels = ['Benign', 'Malignant'])
bottom, top = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_ylim(bottom + 0.5, top - 0.5)
plt.ylabel('True')
plt.xlabel('Prediction')
plt.title("Confusion Matrix");
plt.figure(figsize=(7,17))
```

Comment: Without seeing your code and data, nobody can tell why you are seeing accuracies like that. Please include [a minimal, reproducible code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying Sir. I tried to add all as good as i can.